# Starting a Windows Process or Service with a GUI with PowerShell DSC

Tags: user-interface, powershell, service, process, dsc

I have a Unity3D application (a simple .exe) that I'm trying to automate with PowerShell DSC. However, it seems that Unity3D cannot acquire a GPU when started as a Service or background Process, which breaks my application. When started manually via double-clicking the .exe, things work fine.

Is there a way to force DSC to show a GUI when starting a Service or Process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DSC doesn't currently support interactive applications **during** the configuration.  I can think of two solutions:

- Ensure that the user is logging on

  - The user logs on already for whatever reason
  - Setup the user to auto-logon during the config (and be sure to set DSC to reboot.)

    - [Auto Logon setup KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324737)
- Ensure the app runs when the user logs on:

  - Setup a scheduled task to start the app when the user logs on

    - [Schedule Task cmdlet reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816(v=wps.630).aspx)

      - [atLogon trigger reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649821(v=wps.630).aspx)
  - The app is set in the registry to run when the user logs on